# How do I generate a random sample in R using the set.seed() function?

Tags: r, random, rounding-error

I am getting different values whenever I use the set.seed() command compared to the ones given as correct answers despite using the same command:

```
set.seed(1)
X <- sample(x,25)
mean(X)
```

So, I was advised to run the code below before running the set.seed() command:

```
RNGkind(sample.kind = "Rounding")
```

However, I'm getting this error

```
Error in RNGkind(sample.kind = "Rounding"): 
  unused argument (sample.kind = "Rounding")
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: What version of R are you running? What does `args(RNGkind)` return? The way random numbers were generated in changed in R 3.6. You can get the same numbers if you are using a newer version of R, but if the "answers" were generated in a newer version of R and you are running an older version, you will not be able to get the same results.

Comment: Here is what I get > args(RNGkind)
function (kind = NULL, normal.kind = NULL) 
NULL

Comment: You didn't answer what R version you are running. Running `R.version.string` will tell you. But it sounds like you have an older version of R (pre 3.6). And it seem like the random numbers you are trying to generate may have come from a newer version. You'll probably need to update your R version.